# Use sed to delete all leading/following blank spaces in a text file

Tags: linux, unix, text, sed

File1:

```
  hello  
  world
```

How would one delete the leading/trailing blank spaces within this file using sed - **using one command (no intermediate files)**?

I've currently got:

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' a > b
```

For leading spaces.

```
sed 's/ *$//' b > c
```

And this for trailing spaces.

Comment: While @ghostdog74's answer is a good one, @mouviciel's answer is the *correct* one, according to your question. I upvoted both, but I believe @mouviciel deserves to be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: You are correct - mouviciel is now accepted. Thanks to both mouviciel (correct answer ) and ghostdog74 (directions to awk) for their time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' a > c
```

Moreover on some flavours of `sed`, there is also an option for editing inline:

```
sed -i -e 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' a
```

Comment: I'd also consider matching `\s` which is the generic 'all whitespace characters'.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' a > c`?

Comment: I still see `sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$/' a > c` which does not work for me (bash version 4.3.30, Funtoo-Linux).

Comment: @NikosAlexandris - Thanks, now I see the missing trailing slash. Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

easier way, using awk

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' file
```

or

```
awk '{gsub(/^ +|  +$/,"")}1' file
```

Comment: The first one worked perfectly and is the most simplistic - I know its not what I asked (i.e. sed) - but its so elegant :). I'll look into awk now.

Comment: The first one removes all spurious whitespaces, not only leading and trailing. The second one works best. `awk` is a great tool.

Comment: Ah, I see the other spaces removed with the first one now - the second one works without extra deletions.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -lape 's/^\s+|\s+$//g'
```

Honestly, I know perl regexps the best, so I find `perl -lape` much easier to use than `sed -e`.

Also, to answer the original question, you can have sed execute multiple operations like this:

```
sed -e 's/something/something else/' -e 's/another substitution/another replacement/'
```

Apparently you can also put the two substitutions in one string and separate them with a semicolon, as indicated in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the more general case of applying several filters in a row to an input file without using intermediate files, the solution is to use pipes:

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' a | sed -e 's/ *$//' > c
```

Obviously they are not required here because one invocation of sed is sufficient, but if the second sed command was something different, like uniq or sort, then this pattern is the right one.