# How to delete leading spaces using standart linux utils

Tags: regex, sed, grep, pipe

I'm trying to output to console results of grep without leading spaces. I tried to think out some regexp that will exclude leading zeroes for each line but failed.. 
I found [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593106/use-sed-to-delete-all-leading-following-blank-spaces-in-a-text-file), that it can be made with sed. So I tried this command

```
cat feed* | grep '^.*[{]$' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$/'
```

and got error: sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command

I never used sed before, so I couldn't understand what 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$/' should do even after reading [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).

May be someone can do it just using grep. It'd be perfect (I understand that it can be not practical, but it's interesting to do). And I'll be thankfull a lot if somebody will explain me how sed works with that expression and what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You found a syntax error in an accepted answer with several upvotes :-D

Comment: The problem about using only grep is still open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following solution to remove leading and trailing spaces with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
grep -Po '\S.*?(?=\s*$)' infile
```

It uses the `perl` flavour and prints only what matches, and not the whole line. It begins the match with any non-space character and uses a non-greedy quantifier until it can complete the match with blanks until end of line with look-ahead.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the replacement in the second `sed` expression.  Say:

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'
                              ^
                              |
                              |== This was missing thereby causing the error
```

Comment: This answer completely shows how to make it work. But what about using grep only?